# Compilation error

Tags: c, makefile

Can anybody help me?

```
gcc   -o uartsim.exe xtmpmain.o uartsim.o fiber_driver.o xtmp_options.o getopt.o D:\usr\xtensa\XtDevToolsDE\install\tools\RB-2008.4-win32\XtensaTools\lib\iss\xtmp.lib
gcc: xtmpmain.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [uartsim.exe] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to build an executable (uartsim.exe) and some of the things you need to build it aren't present. That is to say, you haven't built the .o files before trying to link them into an exe. Your makefile is probably broken.

Comment: That is not correct ..actually it was due to a space problem in the makefile that i was compiled.

Comment: Yes, a space problem (I'm assuming you mean spaces in the wrong places? My usual makefile mistake is spaces where there should be tabs) would count as a broken makefile.